# How to repeat last two frames in sprite animation

Tags: jquery, animation, sprite

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to loop last 2 frames once the whole animation is done.

For example I have sprite animation made out of 8 steps. It should go once from 1 to 6 and then I want steps from 7-8 to loop forever.

Now I'm pretty sure it can't be done that way, so I was thinking maybe just make animation from 1 to 6 and then have jQuery to replace class (that has another sprite) at exact time when the first sprite is complete, what do you think?

Comment: You absolutely can make it repeat the last two frames. See this guide for a good tutorial on spritesheets: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-sprite-sheet-animations-steps You'll need to make a seperate animation for the two-frame piece. You should set an animation delay on the two-frame animation to delay it until the previous animation has finished, and set a different position for the keyframe and background position.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't have a clue it could be done that way, that makes things so much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by chaining multiple CSS keyframe animations together. Here's an example below where a 10-step animation plays out once over .8s, then a second keyframe animation (`loop`) consisting of the last 2 frames of the image repeats infinitely (with an initial starting delay of .8s).

```css
.hi {
  width: 50px;
  height: 72px;
  background-image: url("http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png");
  animation: play .8s steps(10) 1,
             loop .2s steps(2) .8s infinite;
}

@keyframes play {
  from {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -500px;
  }
}

@keyframes loop {
  from {
    background-position: -400px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hi"></div>
```

Comment: hahah, thanks for your reply and example, I was surprised this could be done this way!